# Minimizing the number of connected-checks in finding a shortest path in an implicit graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

I'm quite surprised I couldn't find anything on this anywhere, it seems to be a problem that should be quite well known:

Consider the Euclidean shortest path problem, in two dimensions.  Given a set of obstacle polygons *P* and two points *a* and *b*, we want to find the shortest path from *a* to *b* not intersecting the (interior of) any *p* in *P*.

To solve this, one can create the visibility graph for this problem, the graph whose nodes are the vertices of the elements of *P*, and where two nodes are connected if the straight line between them does not intersect any element of *P*.  The edge weight for any such edge is simply the Euclidean distance between such two points.  To solve this, one can then determine the shortest path from a to b in the graph, let's say with A*.

However, this is not a good approach.  Creating the visibility graph in advance requires checking if any two vertices from any two polygons are connected, a check that has higher complexity than determining the distance between two nodes.  So working with a modified version of A* that "does everything what it can before checking if two nodes are actually connected" actually speeds up the problem.

Still, A* and all other shortest path problems always start with an explicitly given graph for which adjacent vertices can be traversed cheaply.  So my question is, is there a good (optimal?) algorithm for finding a shortest path between two nodes a and b in an "implicit graph" that minimizes checking if two nodes are connected?

**Edit:**

To clarify what I mean, this is an example of what I'm looking for:

Let `V` be a set, `a`, `b` elements of `V`.  Suppose `w: V x V -> D` is a weighing function (to some linearly ordered set `D`) and `c: V x V -> {true, false}` returns true iff two elements of `V` are considered to be connected.  Then the following algorithm finds the shortest path from `a` to `b` in `V`, i.e., returns a list `[x_i | i < n]` such that `x_0 = a`, `x_{n-1} = b`, and `c(x_i, x_{i+1}) = true` for all `i < n - 1`.

```
Let (V, E) be the complete graph with vertex set V.
do
    Compute shortest path from a to b in (V, E) and put it in P = [p_0, ..., p_{n-1}]
    if P = empty (there is no shortest path), return NoShortestPath
    Let all_good = true
    for i = 0 ... n - 2 do
        if c(p_i, p_{i+1}) == false, remove edge (p_i, p_{i+1}) from E, set all_good = false and exit for loop
while all_good = false
```

For computing the shortest paths in the loop, one could use A* if an appropriate heuristic exists.  Obviously this algorithm produces a shortest path from `a` to `b`.

Also, I suppose this algorithm is somehow optimal in calling `c` as rarely as possible.  For its found shortest path, it must have ruled out all shorter paths that the function `w` would have allowed for.

But surely there is a better way?

**Edit 2:**

So I found a solution that works relatively well for what I'm trying to do: Using A*, when relaxing a node, instead of going through the neighbors and adding them to / updating them in the priority queue, I put all vertices into the priority queue, marked as hypothetical, together with hypothetical f and g values and the hypothetical parent.  Then, when picking the next element from the priority queue, I check if the node's connection to its parent is actually given.  If so, the node is progressed as normal, if not, it is discarded.

This greatly reduces the number of connectivity checks and improves performance for me a lot.  But I'm sure there's still a more elegant way, in particular one where the "hypothetical new path" doesn't just extend by length one (parents are always actual, not hypothetical).

Answer (score 2):

A* or Dijkstra's algorithm do not need an explicit graph to work, they actually only need:

1. source vertex (`s`)
2. A function `next:V->2^V` such that `next(v)={u | there is an edge from v to u }`
3. A function `isGoal:V->{0,1}` such that `isGoal(v) = 1` iff `v` is a target node.
4. A weight function `w:E->R` such that w(u,v)= cost to move from u to v

And, of course, in addition A* is going to need a heuristic function `h:V->R` such that `h(v)` is the cost approximation.

With these functions, you can generate only the portion of the graph that is needed to find shortest path, on the fly.

In fact, A* algorithm is often used on infinite graphs (or huge graphs that do not fit in any existing storage) in artificial inteliigence problems using this approach.

The idea is, you only look on edges in A* from a given node (all `(u,v)` in `E` for some given `u`). You don't need the entire edges set `E` in order to do it, you can just use your `next(u)` function instead.

Comment: That's roughly what I'm doing and meant by "does everything what it can before checking if two nodes are actually connected."  In fact, I go a little further and, when relaxing a node u, check for every v first if it is already in the closed set, or if it's in the open set and its new g will not improve, before checking if u and v are actually adjacent.  However, A* will still call checks of connectivity (or your `next`) unnecessarily often, for example when relaxing the start node.  An algorithm that does not do that is what I'm looking for.